# Two foreach statements with variables

Tags: php, html, wordpress, foreach

I'm trying to create a URL based upon the number of categories I have. The expected output I want is:

```
<a href="http://lart.co.uk/?cat=13" title="Category Name">Dance</a>
<a href="http://lart.co.uk/?cat=19" title="Category Name">Fashion</a>
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
<a href="http://lart.co.uk/?cat=13" title="Category Name">
<a href="http://lart.co.uk/?cat=19" title="Category Name">
Dance</a> Fashion</a> </a>
```

It's almost what I want, but clearly I'm still off by quite a bit. I'm using 3 foreach statements to get this result. I've tried nesting a foreach but that didn't work. The problem is getting the results from one foreach to pass into another.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
      $categories = get_the_category();
      $separator = ', ';
      if($categories) {
        foreach($categories as $category) {
          $output .= $category->cat_name.$separator;
          $cat_id[] = $category->cat_ID;
        } 
         foreach($cat_id as $id) {
          $category_link = get_category_link( $id ); ?>
          <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">
          <?php }       
        $strarr = explode(',',$output);
        foreach($strarr as $string) { 
         echo $string .'</a>';
         }

       } ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something much simpler like this should perfectly suffice:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    printf('<a href="%s" title="Category Name">%s</a>',
           htmlspecialchars(get_category_link($category->cat_ID)),
           htmlspecialchars($category->cat_name));
}
```

You just need to loop over your categories, outputting one link per category. Nothing more.

Comment: wow, that's one damn fine answer. The only qualm I have about this, though, is how would I go about placing a '/' between each link but not the last link. Sort of like "dance/fashion/music"?

Comment: Instead of outputting it directly, put each link into an array: `$links[] = sprintf(...)`, then after the loop implode them: `echo implode('/', $links)`.

Comment: thanks for introducing me to htmlspecialchars I shall keep this in mind in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You are complicating yourself, i've corrected your code

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $separator = ', ';
    if($categories) {
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $output .= $category->cat_name.$separator;
            $cat_id[] = $category->cat_ID;
        } 
        foreach($cat_id as $id) {
            $category_link = get_category_link( $id ); 
            $cat_name = get_cat_name($id);?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="<?php echo $cat_name;?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></a>
            <?php 
        }
    } 
?>
```

codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name

Comment: This works, thank you I knew I was doing something stupid. Now I'm spoilt for choice, yours more resembles the answer and the method I was looking for but one of the answers below does it in half of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php
  $categories = get_the_category();
  $separator = ', ';
  if($categories) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
      $output .= $category->cat_name.$separator;
      $cat_id[] = $category->cat_ID;
    } 
     foreach($cat_id as $id) {
      $category_link = get_category_link( $id ); ?>
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">
      <?php        
    $strarr = explode(',',$output);
    foreach($strarr as $string) { 
     echo $string .'</a>';
     }
     }

   } ?>
```

Comment: Instead of just "correcting" wrong code it might be useful for Kyle to explain what is wrong, why is it wrong and how he could correct it himself ;)

Comment: The only thing I've noticed with the code yo have provided is that you've nested the foreach. I've tried this, didn't work and it doesn't provide the right output that I stated in the question. Thanks for the effort though :)